# rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check fails for included files using launch file arguments

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

maybe this is a very special usecase but I encountered some missmatching between the behaviour of roslaunch and the result of rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check.

In detail:
I tried to setup a launch file with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

<!-- define arg -->
<arg name="pkg_arg" default="$(find my_pkg)"/>

<!-- use arg -->
<param name="param1" value="$(arg pkg_arg)"/> <!-- this is working, test is ok -->
<include file="$(arg pkg_arg)/included.launch"/> <!-- this is working too, but test fails-->

</launch>
```

trying to use a launch file argument to find an include file. The behaviour when roslaunching the file is fine, the parameter gets uploaded and the included.launch file gets included. Perfect.
But when I add a rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check for that file I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rostest/bin/roslaunch-check.py", line 86, in <module>
error_msg = check_roslaunch_file(roslaunch_path)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rostest/bin/roslaunch-check.py", line 48, in check_roslaunch_file
error_msg = roslaunch.rlutil.check_roslaunch(roslaunch_file)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/rlutil.py", line 206, in check_roslaunch
base_pkg, file_deps, missing = roslaunch.depends.roslaunch_deps([f])
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/depends.py", line 239, in roslaunch_deps
rl_file_deps(file_deps, launch_file, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/depends.py", line 146, in rl_file_deps
parse_launch(launch_file, file_deps, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/depends.py", line 131, in parse_launch
_parse_launch(launch_tag.childNodes, launch_file, file_deps, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/depends.py", line 82, in _parse_launch
sub_launch_file = resolve_args(tag.attributes['file'].value)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/substitution_args.py", line 216, in resolve_args
resolved = _arg(resolved, a, args, context)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/substitution_args.py", line 167, in _arg
raise ArgException(arg_name)
roslib.substitution_args.ArgException: pkg_arg
```

My guess is that something in the cmake macro for checking roslaunch files is wrong. Can somebody point me to the right location?

Best,
Florian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38241/rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check-fails-for-included-files-using-launch-file-arguments/) by [weisshardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1163/weisshardt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2012-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The argument `pkg_arg` get substituted by the absolute path to the package `my_pkg` which could for example be the string `/home/user/ros/my_pkg`. Hence `rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check` could check the current ROS_PACKAGE_PATH for the existence of this package and the file `included.launch` as roslaunch does when executing.
The value for the argument is determined by the current ROS_PACKAGE_PATH which can be checked offline in my opinion.

By the way, the behaviour is the same as hardcoding the argument to point to `my_pkg`:

```
<arg name="pkg_arg" default="/home/user/ros/my_pkg"/>
```

So why shouldn't it be possible to check this?

---

Originally posted by [weisshardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1163/weisshardt/) with karma: 106 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-10**:
Because `rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check()` runs during `make test`, and that argument is not set until the launch file actually runs.